# test code which modifies database without changing the database state

Tags: sql, node.js, unit-testing, dbunit

how to test a . function which actually modifies database without actually changing the data or the database state. How can we achieve it using dbunit ?

I have a model function

```
const newValue = await app.models.module.functionname({
       id: '005q21', typoe: 'XXX', isActive: false
});
```

which actually writes a row in db and return type of newValue is an object. How can i write a unit test which actually runs on production and validates the function against database without changing the live data . (using dbunit )

I am writing test for a node.js /sql application using mocha

Answer (score 0):

> How can i write a unit test which actually runs on production and
>   validates the function against database

That's dbUnit standard functionality, so start with one of the *TestCase approaches such as [PrepAndExpectedTestCase](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/testcases/PrepAndExpectedTestCase.html).

Just have dbUnit compare expected data and it will check the DB for you, non-destructively as normal.

> without changing the live data

1. Don't configure any prep data and it won't insert any rows.
2. On the configured database tester, configure it to not update tables:

   a. Set the SetUpOperation to DatabaseOperation.NONE

   b. Set the TearDownOperation to DatabaseOperation.NONE

   Note that with TearDownOperation set to DatabaseOperation.NONE, the test-created row will remain in the database.  This may be what you want, but typically want dbUnit to cleanup the created rows when done (all rows or the specific rows; see DatabaseOperation options).

Comment: The problem is that the application is in node.js and so are the unit test, and i couldn't find a dbunit equivalent using npm / node.js.  I  need to figure out a test strategy where a clean setup of database is craeted for each test, followed by the test itself.   DB unit is an option but whats in node.js ?  Please suggest